# tkFileDialog AttributeError

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, filedialog

I am having trouble using `tkFileDialog.askopenfile()` in Python 2.7.11

The following code produces the error.

```
import Tkinter

print Tkinter.TkVersion
Tkinter.tkFileDialog.askopenfile(filetypes=[('csvfiles','.csv')])
```

The Python Shell output is:

```
8.5

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/User1/Desktop/tmp.py", line 4, in <module>
    Tkinter.tkFileDialog.askopenfile(filetypes=[('csvfiles','.csv')])
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'tkFileDialog'
>>>
```

If I'm making a terribly stupid mistake then I apologize but I can't seem to find it. Otherwise, are there other dialog boxes I can use in Tkinter to have a user select a file? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for `python 2.7` its a separate module:

```
from tkFileDialog import askopenfilename
```

In `python 3` its included in `tkinter` :

```
from tkinter import filedialog as fd
```